# How do I get the height and width of my character stream on a ggplot2 figure in user coordinates?

Tags: r, ggplot2, character, size

Finding character stream height and width in user coordinates.

```
library (ggplot2)
ggplot_build(figure)
```

doesn't seem to help

I am using `annotate("text", label = ...)`
Simple example code in RStudio:

```
    x_pts <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
    y_pts <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
    df <- data.frame(x_pts, y_pts)
    ggp <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x_pts, y_pts))
    ggp <- ggp + geom_point(size = 1, color = "blue")
    ggp <- ggp + annotate("text", x = 3, y = 4, label = "Data Points",    color = "black")
    print(ggp)
```

End example code.  I wish to find the length and width of the character stream "Data Points" in user coordinates on the plot.  I plan to do some manipulations of the annotation, such as to choose a font size that will cause it to occupy a certain area on the figure.

Comment: Welcome to SO @george-yost. I can prophesize that this question will be downvoted and there is a high chance of it being neglected. Do you want to know, WHY? If `yes` then read here on how to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thereafter edit your post accordingly.

Comment: I don't know a simple way to do this. It might be worth reviewing the source code for `geom_label` (which must do something similar) here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-label.R   or  review https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfittext/index.html, which might have the same functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Great, thank you Jon Spring.  With a great deal of effort I now have geom_fit_text working.  It seems to re-draw the entire figure with each iteration, all 1000 points plus curves.  So it took over a minute to do each label.  By putting the geom_fit_text first, before any other drawing, it works in a couple seconds.  I also have to do all labels in a single call, with vectors, or it will overwrite the previous one with the next call.  Just requires advance planning.